# Extracting the row names of a python pandas dataframe as a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to extract the row names of a python pandas dataframe as a pandas series?
Thanks!

```
# packages
import numpy as np   
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

# the mt cars dataset 
mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("mtcars", "datasets", cache=True).data
df = pd.DataFrame(mtcars)
df = df[1:5]

# DESIRED OUTCOCME - SOMETHING THAT LOOKS LIKE 'desired_series'  
row_names = np.array(['Mazda RX4 Wag','Datsun 710','Hornet 4 Drive','Hornet Sportabout'])
desired_series = pd.Series(row_names)
print(desired_series)

0        Mazda RX4 Wag
1           Datsun 710
2       Hornet 4 Drive
3    Hornet Sportabout
dtype: object)
```

Comment: If the row names can't be extracted as a pandas series, can they be extracted as a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass index values to `Series` constructor:

```
s = pd.Series(df.index)
print (s)
0        Mazda RX4 Wag
1           Datsun 710
2       Hornet 4 Drive
3    Hornet Sportabout
dtype: object
```

Or if use [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html) s necessary create default index by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` for default `RangeIndex`, because index and values are same by default:

```
print (df.index.to_series())
Mazda RX4 Wag            Mazda RX4 Wag
Datsun 710                  Datsun 710
Hornet 4 Drive          Hornet 4 Drive
Hornet Sportabout    Hornet Sportabout
dtype: object

s = df.index.to_series().reset_index(drop=True)
0        Mazda RX4 Wag
1           Datsun 710
2       Hornet 4 Drive
3    Hornet Sportabout
dtype: object
```

Another idea is pass `index` parameter with `np.arange` by length of `DataFrame`:

```
s = df.index.to_series(index=np.arange(len(df)))
print (s)
0        Mazda RX4 Wag
1           Datsun 710
2       Hornet 4 Drive
3    Hornet Sportabout
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly:

```
desired_series = df.index.to_series()
```

Comment: @jezrael: in my tests,`type(df.index.to_series())` is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`